# Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL using The Adjacency List Model

Tags: php, mysql, sql, hierarchical-data

I would like to retrieve all categories with parent in order to create a breadcrumb path. for that reason I create the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE category(
        category_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        parent INT DEFAULT NULL
);
INSERT INTO category VALUES(1,'ELECTRONICS',NULL),(2,'TELEVISIONS',1),(3,'TUBE',2),
        (4,'LCD',2),(5,'PLASMA',2),(6,'PORTABLE ELECTRONICS',1),(7,'MP3 PLAYERS',6),(8,'FLASH',7),
        (9,'CD PLAYERS',6),(10,'2 WAY RADIOS',6);

SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY category_id;

+-------------+----------------------+--------+
| category_id | name                 | parent |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
|           1 | ELECTRONICS          |   NULL |
|           2 | TELEVISIONS          |      1 |
|           3 | TUBE                 |      2 |
|           4 | LCD                  |      2 |
|           5 | PLASMA               |      2 |
|           6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |      1 |
|           7 | MP3 PLAYERS          |      6 |
|           8 | FLASH                |      7 |
|           9 | CD PLAYERS           |      6 |
|          10 | 2 WAY RADIOS         |      6 |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

With the example I follow I can retrieve the information using the following SQL:

```
SELECT t1.name AS lev1, t2.name as lev2, t3.name as lev3, t4.name as lev4
FROM category AS t1
LEFT JOIN category AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.category_id
LEFT JOIN category AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.category_id
LEFT JOIN category AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.category_id
WHERE t1.name = 'ELECTRONICS';
```

The problem I found is before being able to see the full path of a category we have to know the level at which it resides.

my question, is there a way to retrieve the information as the following example but not defining the exact amount of levels?

```
+-------------+----------------------+-------------+-------+
| lev1        | lev2                 | lev3        | lev4  |
+-------------+----------------------+-------------+-------+
| ELECTRONICS | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS | MP3 PLAYERS | FLASH |
```

my idea is to retrieve lev1 or lev2 etc taking into consideration the depth level.

UPDATE:

EXAMPLE OUTPUT

```
ELECTRONICS
ELECTRONICS / TELEVISIONS
ELECTRONICS / TELEVISIONS / TUBE
ELECTRONICS / TELEVISIONS / LCD
ETC
ETC
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support recursive hierarchical queries.  So AFAIK in MySQL you would need to know how many levels deep to query, and how many columns you want in your wide output format.

Comment: what exactly output you want ?  can you give one example

Comment: @Mr.Bhosale UPDATED QUESTION

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Im trying to retrieve it in PHP (laravel)

Comment: MySQL 8.0.2 and MariaDB 10.2 will have "Recursive CTSs".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround.

You can add collateral `PATH` column. The column should have chain of ids from the elemetn to parent. Thus for the root the column empty. All the children of root has _

```
+-------------+----------------------+--------+--------+
| category_id | name                 | parent | path   |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+--------+
|           1 | ELECTRONICS          |   NULL |        |
|           2 | TELEVISIONS          |      1 |1_      |
|           3 | TUBE                 |      2 |1_2_    |
|           4 | LCD                  |      2 |1_2_    |
|           5 | PLASMA               |      2 |1_2_    |
|           6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |      1 |1_      |
|           7 | MP3 PLAYERS          |      6 |1_6_    |
|           8 | FLASH                |      7 |1_6_7_  |
|           9 | CD PLAYERS           |      6 |1_6_    |
|          10 | 2 WAY RADIOS         |      6 |1_6_    |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+--------+
```

On insert a new node you just copy parent node path and add '_'
So to retrieve all children of a node you just use

```
SELECT * 
FROM THE_TABLE
WHERE PATH LIKE '<parent node path>%'
```

There is a restriction of the field size and amount of levels though

Comment: so including the complete path. but its not possible to use the parentid as the recursive information? thank you in advance

Comment: This is a clever workaround, but with the caviat that the `path` itself would be hard to maintain.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not hard to maintain. It could be done by trigger ON PARENT_ID change or to remove the PARENT_ID totally and use the PATH instead.